# Tips for golfing in Subleq

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Subleq](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Subleq) is a programming language with **only one** instruction. Each instruction contains 3 parameters. Code and data space is the same. How it works:

```
A B C
```

A, B and C are signed ints. Instructions are executed in the next way:

```
*B = *B - *A
if(*B <= 0) goto C;
```

One post is one tip. Write your tips for Subleq here!

[Online interpreter, assembler and C to Subleq converter](http://mazonka.com/subleq/online/hsqjs.cgi)

Comment: So, you could goto a number that isn't a multiple of 3 and therefore jump into an instruction, so to speak?

Comment: @Neil yes. you can

Answer (score 5):

## Third Argument in Output Command is Extra Memory

Subleq specifies output with the three word command `x -1 y`, where x is the address of the value to be output. Unlike other Subleq commands, execution will proceed to the next command in all cases and `y` is ignored.  This means it is available to be used for memory.

For example `0:2 -1 65` will print the "A" (CHAR(65)) stored in 2: and then proceed to 3:.